# Python. Imaplib moving mail to Trash

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I have read some solutions but none apparently worked, maybe because of Gmail, I'm not sure, the thing is I want to move my emails from INBOX to Trash and this is what I do:

```
def process_mailbox():
    message={}

    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

    try:
        M.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        print "LOGIN FAILED!!! "
        # ... exit or deal with failure...

    rv, mailboxes = M.list()

    print mailboxes

    if rv == 'OK':

        M.select("INBOX")
        rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "No messages found!"


    for num in data[0].split(): #Read all the mails
        rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
            return

        msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

        #print 'Subject %s: %s' % (num, msg['Subject'])
        message['Subject']=msg['Subject']
        print 'Subject: '+message['Subject']
        if msg.get_content_type() == "text_plain": #No Multipart messages

            body = msg.get_payload()       
            message['Body']=body


        else:    #Multipart messages
            for part in msg.walk():
                if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain": # ignore attachments/html


                     message['Body']=body
                     #print message['Body']



        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            print "Local Date:", local_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            message['Date']=local_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        #send_mail(message)

        #insert_vulnerability_mail(message['Subject'],message['Date'],message['Body'].encode('utf-8'))
        # M.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
        M.copy(num,'[Gmail]/Trash')
    M.close()
    M.logout()
```

So, as you can see, is: M.copy(num,'[Gmail]/Trash') and the result is that I move some emails, lets say, if I have 7 I move 4 out of 7, then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 116, in <module>
    process_mailbox()
  File "mail.py", line 75, in process_mailbox
    msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Which I don't understand because when I execute next time the programm I move more emails, get the error on an other email, execute and I end up moving everything, but I have to execute several times.

Does anyone know what is going on¿? Thank you on advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
imap.store(mail_to_be_deleted, '+FLAGS', r'(\Deleted)')
```